# Javascript/Typescript equivalent for python fn.__module__

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, prototype

Basically the title. In python, I can do the following:

mymodule.py

```
def foo():
  pass
```

main.py

```
import mymodule

print(mymodule.foo.__module__)  # prints mymodule
```

is there an equivalent in javascript or typescript? I know it is possible to get the name of a fn, like `foo.name`, but not sure how to also get the module.

Comment: Basically the file name?

Comment: it doesn't have to be the filename, although that would suffice. In theory I could import something like `import * as bar from 'foo'` and ideally id get bar out. But for my purposes I just need a unique-but-consistent identifier, so file path should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really can if you are using ESM, but a thing you could do to mimic Python would be this:

```
// foo.js
export function foo() {
  return 42;
}

export const __module__ = import.meta.url;
```

Then you could use it when importing the module:

```js
// index.js
import * as foo from './foo.js';

console.log(foo.__module__); // file://.../foo.js
```